# How to sort the Arraylist so specific items come to top

Tags: java, android

I have a recyclerview inflated with the list of contact.

[Check the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXd2c.jpg)

what i want is in the image the red marked contacts should appear on the top of recyclerview

I tried this piece of code but its not working with me.

```
 Collections.sort(userList, new Comparator<Contact>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Contact contact, Contact contact2) {
                return Boolean.compare(contact2.isRegistered(),contact.isRegistered());
            }
        });

        AllContactsAdapter contactAdapter = new AllContactsAdapter(userList,getContext());
        ContactRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        ContactRecyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
```

Hope i get the answers and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Just interchange the Contact objects inside the compare method

```
public void sort() {
    List<Contact> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    userList.add(new Contact("ABC", true));
    userList.add(new Contact("BCD", false));
    userList.add(new Contact("CDE", true));
    userList.add(new Contact("DEF", true));
    userList.add(new Contact("EFG", false));
    userList.add(new Contact("FGH", true));
    userList.add(new Contact("GHI", true));

    Collections.sort(userList, (contact, contact2) -> 
            Boolean.compare(contact.isRegistered(), contact2.isRegistered())); <----Here

    for (Contact contact : userList) {
        System.out.println(contact);
    }
}
```

> Contact{name='BCD', isRegistered=false}
>
> Contact{name='EFG', isRegistered=false}
>
> Contact{name='ABC', isRegistered=true}
>
> Contact{name='CDE', isRegistered=true}
>
> Contact{name='DEF', isRegistered=true}
>
> Contact{name='FGH', isRegistered=true}
>
> Contact{name='GHI', isRegistered=true}

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Comparable interface in your Contact Class
Please check the below example.

Contact.java

```
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact> {

private int id;
private String name;
private boolean isRegistered;

public Contact(int id, String name, boolean isRegistered) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.isRegistered = isRegistered;
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isRegistered() {
    return isRegistered;
}

public void setRegistered(boolean registered) {
    isRegistered = registered;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Contact contact) {

    boolean registered=((Contact) contact).isRegistered();
    return Boolean.compare(this.isRegistered,registered);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Contact [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", isRegistered=" + isRegistered + "]";
}
```

}

Main Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ArrayListExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

        contacts.add(new Contact(1, "Alex",false));
        contacts.add(new Contact(4, "Brian", true));
        contacts.add(new Contact(3, "David",true));
        contacts.add(new Contact(5, "Charles", false));
        contacts.add(new Contact(2, "Edwin", false));

        Collections.sort(contacts);
        System.out.println(contacts);
    }
}
```

And Output is

> [Contact [id=1, name=Alex, isRegistered=false], Contact [id=5, name=Charles, isRegistered=false], Contact [id=2, name=Edwin, isRegistered=false], Contact [id=4, name=Brian, isRegistered=true], Contact [id=3, name=David, isRegistered=true]] 
>   Blockquote